# why Java buffered reader missed a lot of lines in output large txt file as input?

Tags: java, filereader

Hi I using following code

```
public class Readfiles {

    FileInputStream fr;

    public void readAll(){


    try {
        fr = new FileInputStream(new File("books/Artificial intelligence.txt"));


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
     decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);

    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fr, decoder);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

        try {
            int i = 0;


             for(String newLine; (newLine = br.readLine()) != null; )
                {

                newLine = br.readLine();

                i++;


                System.out.println(newLine);    
            }
            br.close();
            System.out.println(i);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

}

To read this txt file it is about 420.000 lines long:
[Artificial intelligence.txt](http://www.myown-it.de/Artificial%20intelligence.txt)

**But my code above dont read it correctly it is missing about half of the lines in the middle, and seems to start anywhere (each start randomly) the following is one of the possible result of the SYSOut :**

Only first lines:

```
#@Margaret H. Szymanski,Paul M. Aoki,Rebecca E. Grinter,Amy Hurst,James D. Thornton,Allison Woodruff
#cComputer Supported Cooperative Work
#%5488
#%87739
#%257074
#%818174
#!
#*Unpacking Tasks: The Fusion of New Technology with Instructional Work.
#t2008
#index831790
#%174882
#!
```

So the question is Why?

Printout of i is always 209647.

Comment: Oh you are so right stupid failure, thanks it is fixed!

Answer (score 4):

Well you are reading the line twice

once in

```
 for(String newLine; (newLine = br.readLine()) != null; )
            {
```

and then again in

```
            newLine = br.readLine();
```

**nicer** would be

```
while ((newLine = br.readLine()) != null) {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `br.readLine()` twice in your loop, but only using the result of one of those two calls in  your `System.out.println` call.  So you're only printing out every second line.

Comment: Oh you are so right stupid failure, thanks it is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `br.readLine()` twice

```
for(String newLine; (newLine = br.readLine()) != null; )
{

    newLine = br.readLine();

    i++;


    System.out.println(newLine);    
}
```

You can get rid of the one inside the loop

```
for(String newLine; (newLine = br.readLine()) != null; )
{

    i++;


    System.out.println(newLine);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String newLine; (newLine = br.readLine()) != null; )
        {

            i++;

            System.out.println(newLine);
        }
```